# Why mouseleave is triggering all the time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseevent

I am trying to create a map, and a certain position of this map should highlight when i hover the  mouse over a button. When the mouse enters the overlay image is displayed as it should be but when the mouse moves, inside the hover button, the overlay image is flashing  and the mouseEnter and mouseLeave events are triggered repeatedly.  I also tried with mouseOver, hover and mouseout with the same result. Am I doing something wrong?

HTML:

```
  <div id="map">
                <img src="images/map/map.png" />                    
                <img src="images/map/mapHover.png" id="hoverhighlands" class="hoverButton"/>
                <img src="images/map/mapHover.png" id="hovernorth" class="hoverButton"/>
                <img src="images/map/mapHover.png" id="hovercentral" class="hoverButton"/>
                <img src="images/map/mapHover.png" id="hoverlothian"class="hoverButton" />                    <img src="images/map/mapHover.png" id="hoverwest" class="hoverButton" />
                <img src="images/map/central.png" class="mapOverlay" id="central" />
                <img src="images/map/highlands.png" class="mapOverlay" id="highlands" />
                <img src="images/map/lothian.png" class="mapOverlay" id="lothian" />
                <img src="images/map/northeast.png" class="mapOverlay" id="north"/>
                <img src="images/map/west.png" class="mapOverlay" id="west"/>
            </div>
```

JS:

```
function setMapOverlays() {
    $(".mapOverlay").hide();
    $(".hoverButton").mouseenter(
        function () {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');            
            id = id.substr(5);

            showOverlay(id);
        }).mouseleave(function () {
            console.log('mouseleave');
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            id = id.substr(5);
            hideOverlay(id);
        })

}

function showOverlay(id) {
    $('#' + id).show();
}

function hideOverlay(id) {
    $('#' + id).hide();
}
```

**EDIT**

Ok, I got why it's not working. When the .show() function triggers my overlay images are placed on top of the hoverButtons, triggering the onmouseleave.

I managed to verify that placing a z-index:2 on hoverButton and z-index:1 on mapOverlay. This way the event is not fired when I move the mouse.

So I have a temporary fix. Moving the onmouseleave event to my mapOverlays instead of my hoverButtons did the trick.
    function setMapOverlays() {
       $(".mapOverlay").hide();
        $(".hoverButton").mouseenter(
            function () {
                console.log('enter');
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                id = id.substr(5);

```
            showOverlay(id);
        });

    $('.mapOverlay').mouseleave(function () {
        console.log('mouseleave');               
        hideOverlay($(this));
    })
}
```

This works BUT it's not the desired behavior. I want the Overlay to hide when my mouse moves out of the hoverButton. Any suggestions on how to do that?

Two images to help explain exactly what I'm doing:

[image: map]

[image: hovered]

Comment: Try putting a semi-colon after the `mouseleave` function. `hideOverlay(id);
        });`

Comment: Thanks but it didn't help. I guess I'm doing something wrong with the overlays. Maybe when I show the image over the hover button it triggers the mouse leave because the button was overlayed by the image?

Comment: Semicolons are not required in javascript unless the proceeding line starts with a [ or a (

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use mouseleave event for hoverButton class. Try instead handle mousemove event in overlay when it shown and check is mous still over element that initiated overlay show method.

```
function setMapOverlays() {
    $(".mapOverlay").hide();
    $(".hoverButton").mouseenter(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        id = id.substr(5);

        showOverlay(id, this);
    });
};

function showOverlay(id, initiator) {
    initiator = $(initiator);
    initiatorBoundary = {
        x1: initiator.offset().left,
        x2: initiator.offset().left + initiator.outerWidth(),
        y1: initiator.offset().top,
        y2: initiator.offset().top + initiator.outerHeight()
    };

    $('#' + id).mousemove(function(event) {
        if (event.pageX < initiatorBoundary.x1 || event.pageX > initiatorBoundary.x2 || event.pageY < initiatorBoundary.y1 || event.pageY > initiatorBoundary.y2) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    }).show();
}​
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/1stein/gDCCx/)

BTW, maybe it's would be easier implement without overlay element. Did you consider to change whole map image on mouseenter and mouseleave?

Comment: This solution works perfectly. I considered doing that, but I don't think replacing the whole map would solve my problem. The blue button would overlay the text (highlands & highlands) and if i set the background image on top, I would get back to the initial problem! Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. Regarding whole map image manipulation: you can draw markers just on map image and place transparent hoverButtons in appropriate positions

Comment: I think right now that would be just extra unnecessary work. Your solution works fine in every browser! But I'll keep it in mind for a next time, or in case we have problems with this!  :)

Answer (score 2):

I fix your js code and add an data-id attribute to img tags

new html is:

```
<div id="map">
    <img src="images/map/map.png" />                    
    <img src="images/map/mapHover.png" id="hoverhighlands" class="hoverButton"  data-id="highlands" />
    <img src="images/map/mapHover.png" id="hovernorth" class="hoverButton"      data-id="north" />
    <img src="images/map/mapHover.png" id="hovercentral" class="hoverButton"    data-id="central" />
    <img src="images/map/mapHover.png" id="hoverlothian"class="hoverButton"     data-id="lothian" />
    <img src="images/map/mapHover.png" id="hoverwest" class="hoverButton"       data-id="west" />
    <img src="images/map/central.png" class="mapOverlay" id="central"           data-id="central" />
    <img src="images/map/highlands.png" class="mapOverlay" id="highlands"       data-id="highlands" />
    <img src="images/map/lothian.png" class="mapOverlay" id="lothian"           data-id="lothian" />
    <img src="images/map/northeast.png" class="mapOverlay" id="north"           data-id="north" />
    <img src="images/map/west.png" class="mapOverlay" id="west"                 data-id="west" />
</div>
```

new jscode is:

```
function setMapOverlays() {
    $(".mapOverlay").hide();

    function showOverlay(id) {
        $('#' + id).show();
    }

    function hideOverlay(id) {
        $('#' + id).hide();
    }

    function hover() {
        console.log('hover', this, arguments);
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        showOverlay(id);
    }

    function leave(evt) {
        console.log('leave', this, arguments);
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var hovered = evt.relatedTarget;
        if ($(hovered).data('id') == id) {
            $(hovered).mouseleave(leave);
            return;
        }
        hideOverlay(id);
    }

    $(".hoverButton")
        .mouseenter(hover)
        .mouseleave(leave);
}
```

you can try this on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rudolfovich/qrcBm/4/)

Comment: This solution almost works. The problem with this is, there is a transparent background in the overlay image. Notice the dark blue takes the whole image, from left till right. and there is a transparent background over there. To trigger the hide I have to move the mouse all the way out of the background. But thanks a lot for your reply. I'm a beginner in javascript and it's very good to see different ways of solving problems!